# Slick.js center mode for 3 slides with navigation

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

Is it possible to just have 3 slides on a Slick.js carousel with navigation so essentially the middle slide becomes larger.

I've setup a codepen showing first how more than 3 slides operates but when you only have 3 slides, Slick.js removes the navigation and it no longer works.

http://codepen.io/mellomedia/pen/GqLjjX

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $(".center").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

That's how slick.js works. It removes any navigation if all slides are showing on the screen. And that's ok behavior.

I recommend you stylize your slides only if navigation is showing:

```
.slick-dotted .slick-current img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

You will got a result like this:

[image]

See the full example: http://codepen.io/gambala/pen/akxBXr

Comment: Thanks Gambala, is there another carousel plugin that would function with navigation and only 3 slides?

Comment: Actually you don't needed another behavior, slick.js doing it as best as possible, I recommend to stay with slick.js and it's behavior.